# Obtaining plots and 95% CIs from boot() function with multiple statistics

Tags: r

I am starting to explore the limits of the `boot()` function in the `boot` package. I have just worked out how to extract multiple statistics from a single call, however I don't know how to index them.

```
bs <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
  return(c(coef(fit), summary(fit)$r.squared)) # four stats extracted 
}
```

Now bootstrap with 1000 replications.

```
(results <- boot(data = mtcars, statistic = bs, R = 1000, formula = mpg ~ wt + disp))
```

Now if we plot and attempt to get 95% CIs for this object we only get the first of the statistics, in this case the intercept for the model.

```
plot(results)
boot.ci(results, type="bca")

# BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
# Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
# 
# CALL : 
#   boot.ci(boot.out = results, type = "bca")
# 
# Intervals : 
#   Level       BCa          
# 95%   (30.27, 39.53 )  
# Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

How do I index the other four parameters, either one-by-one and/or all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first notice that:

```
> head(results$t)
         [,1]      [,2]         [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 35.94765 -4.358146 -0.010605142 0.7471584
[2,] 33.54691 -3.319141 -0.011821276 0.8463980
[3,] 34.01732 -3.627647 -0.009797742 0.6727989
[4,] 32.26678 -1.717800 -0.030443778 0.7466273
[5,] 35.78895 -3.944054 -0.016471864 0.8277447
[6,] 33.99407 -3.560855 -0.014129072 0.8412922
```

So you can just use `result$t[,i]` To access the ith element. It looks like the first column is the intercept, the second is the coefficient on weight, the third is the coefficient on displacement, and the final column is R-squared.

Also you can use `boot.ci(results, type="bca", index=i)` to access the ith column, same goes for plot `plot(results, index=i)`.

Comment: Thanks @fijmenez. I could see they were there in the summary call but didn't know how to get at them. `lapply(1:dim(results$t)[2], function (i) boot.ci(results, type = "bca", index = i))` gets CIs for all four stats into a list.